# How to fix an unexpected quote in sql update

Tags: php, sql

I got an error of unexpected " in the code shown below

Tried to sum columns and then update each row in a SUM-Cell as I run the code.

```
$QQ = "UPDATE T_IMB19 SET SUM1=$SUMA, SUM2=$SUMB, TOTAL=$SUMTOT WHERE Navn=$rows['Navn']";
mysqli_query($con,$QQ);
```

I have echo on the `SUMA`, `SUMB` and `SUMTOT` and they act nicely, but the update doesn't work.

> Error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: Just add a single quote to the variables

Comment: Don't write SQL like that. Also this is a PHP error, not SQL. SQL should be, `UPDATE T_IMB19 SET SUM1=?, SUM2=?, TOTAL=? WHERE Navn=?`.

Comment: ... or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/php

Answer (score 0):

just add double quotes again for each after and before single quotes, and then join it with `.` like below code.

```
$QQ = "UPDATE T_IMB19 SET SUM1=$SUMA, SUM2=$SUMB, TOTAL=$SUMTOT WHERE Navn='" . $rows['Navn'] . "'";
mysqli_query($con,$QQ);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes for the array key when you're within a string.

```
$QQ = "UPDATE T_IMB19 SET SUM1=$SUMA, SUM2=$SUMB, TOTAL=$SUMTOT WHERE Navn='$rows[Navn]'";
mysqli_query($con,$QQ);
```

On a side note you may want to use `PDO` for making your life easier for SQL queries. More docs about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: This works. Thanks for helping comment. :-)